# Implicit cursor conversion due to comments

Tags: sql-server, types, cursor, odbc

I use ODBC in a C++ app to connect to SQL Server
I had implicit cursor conversions happening unexpectedly on simple SELECT query from 'DynamicServer' (and any server side odbc cursor) to 'Client Forward only'

I recently realized that it was due to comments (either /**/ or --) written at the beginning of the query.

I can reproduce this behavior on both 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0' and 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server'

We do send those comments so that query can be easily identified on server side.
Here an example:

No cursor type conversion happens on:

```
SELECT * from table_x
```

But a server cursor cannot be opened with the following query

```
-- selectYY.sql
SELECT * from table_x
```

In addition I noted that a comment with /**/ in the middle of the query or after the query doesn't trigger the cursor conversion

Anyone has a clue of what is going on here?
Is it an expected behavior?

According to the msdn the expected behavior is that batch query (query with multiple statement) are converted to ClientForwardOnly, it seems weird that the initial comment is enough for a query to be seen as batch.

Comment: Could it be the newline that triggers a "batch query"? What happens with this query: `/* -- selectYY.sql */ SELECT * from table_x` ? Or with a query that has a newline in between somewhere (cannot write that properly formated as comment, hope you get the idea), like `select * FROM \r\n table_x`

Comment: I have already try with useless new line and spaces at the beginning and in the middle of the query, it doesn't affect the cursor type

Comment: It is being investigated by SqlServer teams [link](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/3132162)

Answer (score 0):

It is about to be fixed:

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/3132162

Ludovic